# Adding custom methods to Eloquent Model in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have an Eloquent Article model in my Laravel 4 app. It's empty at the moment, but what I want to do is define two methods:

- getNextArticle
- getPreviousArticle

So that when I use:

```
$article = Article::find(1);
```

I can follow up with:

```
$article->getNextArticle;
```

and

```
$article->getPreviousArticle;
```

I need to get access to the results returned from find() within the Articles model so I can use the data to get the next and previous articles from an SQL query.

Theoretically I end up with something like:

```
class Article extends Eloquent
{
    public function getNextArticle()
    {
        // SQL query to get next article from the database
    }

    public function getPreviousArticle()
    {
        // SQL query to get previous article from the database
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Class Article extends Eloquent {

    public function getNextArticle()
    {
        return Article::where('id', '>', $this->id)->take(1)->get();
    }

    public function getPreviousArticle()
    {
        return Article::where('id', '<', $this->id)->take(1)->get();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that  method should be `static` to make it works or use `scope..`, example `public static function getNextArticle()`

Comment: @roll If you make the method static, you lose the ability to use `$this->id`

Answer (score 3):

**Source Laravel** http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent

*Article is redundant so i removed it.*

```
Class Article extends Eloquent {

        public function scopeNext($query)
        {
            return $query->where('id', '>', $this->id)->take(1)->get();
        }

        public function scopePrevious($query)
        {
            return $query->where('id', '<', $this->id)->take(1)->get();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably try it like this... not sure if it would work though

```
 class Article extends Eloquent
  {
    public function getNextArticle()
    {
    return Article::find($this->id+1)->get();
    }

    public function getPreviousArticle()
    {
    return Article::find($this->id-1)->get();
    }
  }
```

Comment: IDs are rarely perfectly sequential, and not necessary representative of the order.

Comment: I have the SQL query to run for the next and previous articles. I'm just trying to figure out how I can create the methods so I can chain it to $article->find(1)->next() for example.